# How to create or set OBJECT data in firebase firestore using Angularfire2?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I would like to use the firestore via Angularfire2 to store a GeoData object, consisting of 2 geopoints and other attributes like distance and radius. How do i create such an object? the following does not work(neither will the dot notation way of referencing object properties):

```
`this.GeoCol.doc(MyGeoDocId).set(
             {'user_name': 'john_doe',
              'user_email':'a.b@c.com',
             'MyGeoObj["geoDistance"]': 500,
             'MyGeoObj["geoRad"]':100,
             'MyGeoObj["geoPt1"]': new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(parseFloat(MyLat1),parseFloat(MyLng1)),
             'MyGeoObj["geoPt2"]':new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(parseFloat(MyLat2),parseFloat(MyLng2))
             } );`
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: thanks Hank, but i forgot to mention that i also have other attributes that is not part of the object in the doc like user name and email. I have updated my example in my question. I am also trying to avoid a sub-sub-collection to store just the GeoObj if i can.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
this.GeoCol.doc(MyGeoDocId).set(
         {
         geoDistance: 500,
         geoRad:100,
         geoPt1: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(parseFloat(MyLat1),parseFloat(MyLng1)),
         geoPt2:new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(parseFloat(MyLat2),parseFloat(MyLng2))
         });
```

You will get `MyGeoObj` when you retrieve `this.GeoCol.doc(MyGeoDocId)`